# What exactly does this javascript getElementsByTagName syntax do?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
var targetTitle = targetElement.getElementsByTagName('title').item(0);
```

Am i passing a plain string into targetTitle? or what am i passing exactly?

Which element would be item(1), item(2), etc... in here:

```
<title>title1</title>
<title><title2</title>
```

Does it just look for ALL the `title` tags on the page and return the 0,1,2/?

Would this return 'title2':

```
targetElement.getElementsByTagName(‘title’).item(1)
```

Comment: What is wrong with me putting your line of code in question in the question body that you have to put it back in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `targetTitle` will contain a reference to the DOM element object for the `title` tag.

The code only gets the first `title` tag, as there is only one in each document.

Comment: what if there are two title tags as in my example

Comment: Look at my edited answer, you're retrieving one of the title elements with `item(n)`, not both.

Comment: @I__: The browser is probably ignoring the second one, so there is really only one. Either way the code is only getting the first.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the first `<title>` element from *targetElement*.

item(0): `<title>title1</title>`
item(1): `<title><title2</title>`

Note: those indexes starts with zero, not one.

Comment: is that a string or what is it?

Comment: That's a HTMLElement object. To get the contents of it, use textContent or innerHTML, like `var title = targetTitle.innerHTML;`.